# str_replace_all does not work when changing system locale. (encoding problem)

Tags: r, encoding, data.table

I have a Korean data and want to do some with `data.table` data format.

I read the data here

```
data = fread("dta.csv",quote="\"",encoding = "UTF-8")
```

And, I have to run this to see the data in Korean

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "korean")
```

I want to use this

```
str_replace_all("123-5","-", "가")
```

but when I run this, I got this result.

```
"123°¡5"
```

If I don't run `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "korean")` then `str_replace_all("123-5","-", "가")` works well but I can't see the Korean data.

Why `stringr::str_replace_all()` does not work when I change the system locale?

Comment: What about the base equivalent `gsub()`?

Comment: It works well.      

gsub("-", "가", "123-5")
[1] "123가5"

Comment: If you take a look [here](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/stringr.html): *"The locale always defaults to English..."*. I guess you have to change the locale separately for `stringr` or just use the base `R` equivalents such as `gsub()` in your example.

Comment: Please [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62133989/3439404)