# How to resolve Devanagari script encoding error in R

Tags: r, character-encoding, devanagari

I have a .csv file which is UTF-8 encoded when I saved it. The script is Devanagari of the data in this file. I am able to see the words in csv file in excel

```
में
लिए
किया
गया
हैं
नहीं
सिंह
पुलिस
दिया
करने
कहा
रहे
बाद
करें
साथ
रहा
```

But when I open that in R, the words do not get encoded correctly. the output for print() is like this:

```
                                                    word
                      à¤¸à¤¾à¤°à¥‡_à¤–à¤¤à¤°à¥‹à¤‚_à¤•à¥‹
                à¤œà¤¾à¤¨à¤¤à¥‡_à¤¹à¥\u0081à¤\u008f_à¤­à¥€
                                   à¤µà¤¿à¤µà¥‡à¤•_à¤¨à¥‡
                                             à¤Ÿà¥€à¤µà¥€
```

How can I resolve this? I have tried `Sys.setlocale()` and `read.delim(wordlist.csv, encoding = "UTF-8")` but neither worked.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62126926/3439404) help to resolve your issue?  Works for `read.delim(wordlist.csv, encoding = "UTF-8")` in pure `R` console for me…

Comment: It might help but I can't go that road since there are 34k rows.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for comment (sorry, I'm a greenhorn in `R`):

```
print( sessionInfo())

library(stringi)
library(magrittr)

x <- read.delim("D:\\bat\\SO\\64497248_devangari.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")
print('=== print(x)')
print(x)
for (line in x){
  y <- line %>% 
    stri_replace_all_regex("<U\\+([[:alnum:]]+)>", "\\\\u$1") %>% 
    stri_unescape_unicode() %>% 
    stri_enc_toutf8()
}

print('=== print(y)')
print(y)

print('=== for (i in y) {print(i)}')
for (i in y) {print(i)}

print('=== print(z)')
z <- x['word'] %>% 
  stri_replace_all_regex("<U\\+([[:alnum:]]+)>", "\\\\u$1") %>% 
  stri_unescape_unicode() %>% 
  stri_enc_toutf8()
print(z)
```

**Output** (in `Rgui.exe` console):

```
> source ( 'D:\\bat\\SO\\64497248.r' )
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Czech_Czechia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Czech_Czechia.1250    LC_MONETARY=Czech_Czechia.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Czech_Czechia.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.1
[1] "=== print(x)"
                                       word
1                  <U+092E><U+0947><U+0902>
2                  <U+0932><U+093F><U+090F>
3          <U+0915><U+093F><U+092F><U+093E>
4                  <U+0917><U+092F><U+093E>
5                  <U+0939><U+0948><U+0902>
6          <U+0928><U+0939><U+0940><U+0902>
7          <U+0938><U+093F><U+0902><U+0939>
8  <U+092A><U+0941><U+0932><U+093F><U+0938>
9          <U+0926><U+093F><U+092F><U+093E>
10         <U+0915><U+0930><U+0928><U+0947>
11                 <U+0915><U+0939><U+093E>
12                 <U+0930><U+0939><U+0947>
13                 <U+092C><U+093E><U+0926>
14         <U+0915><U+0930><U+0947><U+0902>
15                 <U+0938><U+093E><U+0925>
16                 <U+0930><U+0939><U+093E>
[1] "=== print(y)"
 [1] "में"    "लिए"  "किया" "गया"  "हैं"    "नहीं"  "सिंह"  "पुलिस" "दिया" "करने"  "कहा"  "रहे"   "बाद"  "करें"   "साथ"  "रहा" 
[1] "=== for (i in y) {print(i)}"
[1] "में"
[1] "लिए"
[1] "किया"
[1] "गया"
[1] "हैं"
[1] "नहीं"
[1] "सिंह"
[1] "पुलिस"
[1] "दिया"
[1] "करने"
[1] "कहा"
[1] "रहे"
[1] "बाद"
[1] "करें"
[1] "साथ"
[1] "रहा"
[1] "=== print(z)"
[1] "c(\"में\", \"लिए\", \"किया\", \"गया\", \"हैं\", \"नहीं\", \"सिंह\", \"पुलिस\", \"दिया\", \"करने\", \"कहा\", \"रहे\", \"बाद\", \"करें\", \"साथ\", \"रहा\"\n)"
Warning messages:
1: package ‘magrittr’ was built under R version 4.0.2 
2: In stri_replace_all_regex(., "<U\\+([[:alnum:]]+)>", "\\\\u$1") :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
>
```

Comment: Sorry Josef. Maybe you are a pro at coding but I have just started. The code given by you didnt work and I dont know what is Rgui.exe. I run my projects in Rstudio. Additionally, I have a data frame that I want to work upon so i need to fix the encoding instead of trying to print the script because I have to work on that data frame. I dont know how to work with the data frame in theoutput you provided.